# Convergence of a sum similar to Parseval's Indentity

Tags: real-analysis, summation, parsevals-identity

> Suppose that $\{e_n\}$ is a othonormal basis for $L^2[0,T]$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ be the standard $L^2[0,T]$ inner product. Denote $1_A(x)$ as the indicator function on the set $A$. Prove that
> $$
>    \sum_{n=0}^N \langle1_{[0,t]},e_n\rangle\langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle \to \langle 1_{[0,t]}, 1_{[0,s]} \rangle
> $$
> and $N \to \infty$.

I am having trouble seeing why this is true. First suppose $s<t$, I then rewrote the sum as
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^N \left(\langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle + \langle1_{[s,t]},e_n\rangle\right)\langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^N \langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle\langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle  + \sum_{n=0}^N \langle1_{[s,t]},e_n\rangle\langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle   
$$
and by Parsevals Indentity the first sum converges to
$$\langle1_{[0,s]},1_{[0,s]}\rangle$$
and because $s<t$, this is the same thing as
$$ \langle 1_{[0,t]}, 1_{[0,s]} \rangle 
$$
But then this would mean that we would need the second sum to converge to $0$ but I do not see why that is that case.

Comment: Yes, but that does that mean when we are considering $$ \sum_{n=0}^N \langle1_{[s,t]},e_n\rangle\langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle$$ Is there a property I am forgetting? I am guessing that this sum converges to $$ \langle1_{[0,s]},1_{[s,t]}\rangle =0 $$ but do not know how to show the convergence if that is in fact true.

Comment: @user251257 yea I know, I do not have confusion with that. I just don't see why $$ \sum_{n=0}^N \langle1_{[s,t]},e_n\rangle\langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle \to 0 $$

Comment: the second sum does converge to $\langle 1_[s,t] , 1_{[0, s]} \rangle$ which is indeed 0. there is no magic here.

Comment: @user251257 I understand that $$\langle 1_{[s,t]} , 1_{[0, s]} \rangle =0$$ but why does $$ \sum_{n=0}^N \langle1_{[s,t]},e_n\rangle\langle1_{[0,s]},e_n\rangle \to \langle1_{[0,s]},1_{[s,t]}\rangle$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to understand why for $f,g\in L^2$ it follows
$$ \langle f, g \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle f, e_n \rangle \langle g, e_n \rangle. $$

As $\{e_n\}$ is a orthonormal basis, we have
$$ f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle f, e_n \rangle e_n. $$
The same for $g$.
Now, by the continuity of the inner product, we have
$$ \langle f, g \rangle = \lim_{N\to \infty} \bigl\langle \sum_{n=1}^N \langle f, e_n \rangle e_n, \sum_{n=1}^N \langle g, e_n \rangle e_n \bigr\rangle 
= \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \langle f, e_n \rangle \langle g, e_n \rangle, $$
as $\{e_n\}$ are orthogonal.

Comment: In your very first equality you write f twice instead of g

Comment: @badatmath: thx. fixed

Answer (score 0):

I general, we have that the map $f\mapsto \hat f: L^2([0,T])\to \ell_2(\mathbb N,\mathbb C)$ is an isometric isomorphism, so an application of the polarization identity gives $\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_n\hat f(n)\overline{\hat g(n)}$, which is all you need.

Comment: How could I answer my original question by using $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle \hat f,\hat g\rangle$?

Comment: I fixed a typo. Please see my edit. Now it should be clear.